# Retrieving data from Firebase using Google App Engine (Java Servlet)

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, firebase

Ok, so I have followed the tutorials but still no luck.

In my doGet method, I am trying to simply run the following code:

```
Firebase f = new Firebase("https://<My Firebase name>.firebaseio.com");
    f.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.info("Ran listener");

        }

        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.info("didn't run listener");
        }
    });
```

But the logs never run (although the loggers work just find outside of the listener). Does anyone have any ideas? My servlet is using manual scaling and it writes to Firebase just fine, it just cannot seem to grab a snapshot for whatever reason.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: I am pretty sure the issue was with the logging, not the data being accessed. In hindsight I should have attempted to modify Firebase data inside of the callback.